# How to relate weak with weak entity

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship

How can I translate to the relational model a weak entity related to another weak entity which is related to the strong one?

I want to translate this ER MODEL to the relational database structure. So, what I'm wondering is whether this is correct:

```
BOOK_STORE(idBookStore, address); 

SECTION(idBookStore, sectionNumber, surface) 
    WHERE idBookStore REFERS BOOK_STORE; 

SHELL(shellNumber, sectionNumber, idBookStore) 
    WHERE sectionNumber 
    REFERS TO SECTION and 
        idBookStore REFERS TO BOOK_STORE.
```

So my question is: is this correct?

[image: I add an ER-MODEL for being more speceific.]

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I already inserted a picture to be more specific. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: This helps, but I'm still not entirely clear on what you're after. Is this diagram your goal or what you're starting with? What entities do you want to relate to each other specifically?

Comment: I want to translate this ER MODEL to the relational database structure. So, what I'm wondering is whether this is correct... BOOK_STORE(idBookStore, address); SECTION(idBookStore, sectionNumber, surface) WHERE idBookStore REFERS BOOK_STORE; SHELL(shellNumber, sectionNumber, idBookStore) WHERE sectionNumber REFERS TO SECTION and idBookStore REFERS TO BOOK_STORE. SO my question is...is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this create table syntax to implement that ER diagram

```
CREATE TABLE bookStore (
    idBookstore   integer,
    address       text,
    PRIMARY KEY(idBookstore)
);

CREATE TABLE section (
    idBookstore   integer,
    sectionNumber integer,
    surface       text,
    FOREIGN KEY (idBookstore) REFERENCES bookStore.idBookStore,
    PRIMARY KEY (idBookstore, sectionNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE shell (
    idBookstore   integer,
    sectionNumber integer,
    shellNumber   integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (idBookstore) REFERENCES bookStore.idBookStore,
    FOREIGN KEY (sectionNumber) REFERENCES section.sectionNumber,
    PRIMARY KEY (idBookstore, sectionNumber, shellNumber)
);
```

The key point to think about here is what is the key that defines the weak entity. Then you can substitute the primary key of the related entity.

So in this case, `section` has a primary key that's the tuple `(idBookstore,sectionNumber)`. We'll substitute that with `X` for this argument.

The `shell` is related to the section and is a weak entity, so it's key should be `(X, shellNumber)`.  This is the same form as `section`. And we can expand `X` to get the correct foreign key  `(idBookstore, sectionNumber, shellNumber)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE bookStore (
    idBookstore   integer,
    address       text,
    PRIMARY KEY(idBookstore)
);

CREATE TABLE section (
    idBookstore   integer,
    sectionNumber integer,
    surface       text,
    FOREIGN KEY (idBookstore) REFERENCES bookStore.idBookStore,
    PRIMARY KEY (idBookstore, sectionNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE shell (
    idBookstore   integer,
    sectionNumber integer,
    shellNumber   integer,
    FOREIGN KEY (idBookstore) REFERENCES bookStore.idBookStore,
    FOREIGN KEY (sectionNumber) REFERENCES section.sectionNumber,
    PRIMARY KEY (idBookstore, sectionNumber, shellNumber)
);
```